# How do I set up a Google App Engine project with IDEA?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm new to IDEA, but very familiar with Eclipse.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html), but the resultant project has none of the required jars on its path.

I can create a WEB-INF/lib folder and copy the appengine-xx/lib/user/* files into it, and then add them as libraries, however it still lacks other jars, including those containing the javax.servlet packages.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Should the required jars have been added automatically to my new project?

*edit in response to answer:* I've confirmed that the files in the user directory do appear to be part of the Module dependencies, however these do not include, for example, the javax.servlet.* package. This and other packages are in appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4.1/lib/shared - but the AppEngine documentation explicitly states that these should not be bundled with your app (ie. they shouldn't be placed in the lib folder). It seems that these files should have been included at the outset somehow by the AppEngine plugin and shouldn't need to be added manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new App Engine project, all the required libraries are automatically added to the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html):

[image: libraries]

If you need more libraries, you should add them to the [Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) manually and then [configure the Artifact](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html) to include the libs:

[image: artifact]

If you are using API from `lib/shared` in your code, you need to add these jars to the dependencies as well, but with the **Provided** scope (and don't add it to the Artifact).

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer, and I've confirmed that the files in the user directory do appear to be part of the Module dependencies, however these do not include, for example, the javax.servlet.* package.  This and other packages are in appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4.1/lib/shared - but the AppEngine documentation explicitly states that these should not be bundled with your app (ie. they shouldn't be placed in the lib folder).  It seems that these files should have been included at the outset somehow by the AppEngine plugin and shouldn't need to be added manually...